# beginner lua: check array for value

Tags: lua

I need to generate a random number and then check to see which tables (arrays) that number is listed in as a value. After the check is complete I need to output the tables in which the numbers appear.

For example a random number between 1 and 21 would be generated and then be searched for within other tables of numbers.

```
evens = {2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20}
odds = {1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17,19,21}
low = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7}
med = {8,9,10,11,12,13,14}
high = {15,16,17,18,19,20,21}
```

If 17 was the random number, I would need 'odds' and 'high' to be output.

Comment: To make things somewhat simpler, I'm trying to make an 'if' statement that checks if the number is in each table, then executes some other function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most general solution I can offer is to build something like [inverted index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverted_index). You just need to create a record in a table for each possible term(a number, in your case). Values in such table represents arrays in which you can find your term.
The code can look like this:

```
local evens = { 2, 4, 6, 8, name = 'evens'}
local odds = {1, 3, 5, 7, name = 'odds'}
local low = { 1, 2, 3, 4, name = 'low'}
local high = {15, 16, 17, 18, 19, name = 'high'}

local inv_index = {}

function add_to_index(index, numbers)
    for i, number in ipairs(numbers) do
            local indexed = index[number]
            if not indexed then
                    index[number] = { numbers }
            else
                    table.insert(indexed, numbers)
            end
    end
end

add_to_index(inv_index, evens)
add_to_index(inv_index, odds)
add_to_index(inv_index, low)
add_to_index(inv_index, high)

-- which arrays contains the number "4"?
for k, indexed in pairs(inv_index[4]) do
    print(indexed.name) -- prints "evens" and "low"
end
```

The downside of this solution is the memory consumption, especially if the number of possible numbers is big. The alternative is to sort each array and perform a [binary search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) on it. There is an [implementation](http://lua-users.org/wiki/BinarySearch) for lua.

If you can modify your arrays, you can just store numbers in a some kind of set:

```
local evens = { [2] = true, [4] = true, [6] = true, [8] = true }
local low = { [1] = true, [2] = true, [3] = true, [4] = true }
local odds = { [1] = true, [3] = true , [5] = true, [7] = true }

local x = 4

print(evens[x] ~= nil) -- true
print(low[x] ~= nil) -- true
print(odds[x] ~= nil) -- false
```

Answer (score 0):

To check for odd tables are not needed, and getting into the range easier to check on the limits:

```
local low = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7}
local med = {8,9,10,11,12,13,14}
local high = {15,16,17,18,19,20,21}

local n = 33
local function CheckNum(n)
    local tab_type = 'unknown'
    if n  >= 1 and n <=7 then tab_type = "low"
    elseif n  >= 8 and n <=14  then tab_type = "med"
    elseif n  >= 15 and n <=21 then tab_type = "high"   
    end
    local odd = (n%2==0) and "even" or "odd" 
    return odd,  tab_type
end

local odd,  tab_type = CheckNum(n)
print ( odd, " ", tab_type )
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer although I fear I may have oversimplified the tables a bit. Many of the tables I will be using contain non-consecutive numbers; so arranging them with greater than and less than operators isn't really an option.

i.e.: 
{1,4,6,8,9,14,17,18,21}
and {2,3,5,7,10,11,12,13,15,16,19,20}.
Is there no way to tell if a value is in a table without manually iterating through the entire table?

Answer (score 0):

I found a function to check for a value in a list:

```
function contains(list, x)
    for _, v in pairs(list) do
        if v == x then return true end
    end
    return false
end
```

Here's an example how to use it:

```
alist={'abc',123}
if contains(alist,'abc')
    print('abc is in the list alist')
end
```